# How to convert string to int in bash?

Tags: bash

I want an array containing the numbers from 1 to twice the number of lines in a text file. In this example, the file somefile.dat has four lines. I tried:

```
~$ echo {1..$(( `cat somefile.dat | wc -l`*2 ))}
{1..8}
```

which is not what i wanted. However, what goes on inside the parenthesis has clearly been interpreted as integers. Why then, is the total result a string? And how do I convert it to an int so that I get the numbers 1 to 8 as output?

Comment: Consider using `wc -l < file` to get the number directly. So can you do `val=$(wc -l < file)`.

Comment: Works in zsh. Just sayin',

Comment: `cat somefile.dat | wc -l | perl -nle'for(1..$_*2){print;}'`

Comment: `cat somefile.dat somefile.dat | wc -l`

Comment: If the only thing you are going to do is iterate over the array, it's probably going to be simpler to just use a `for((i=1; i<=$(wc -l <somefile.dat)*2; i++))` loop

Comment: Or, as anubhava suggests, [`seq`](http://man.cx/seq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why then, is the total result a string?

That is because brace range directive in shell `{1..10}` doesn't support a variable in it.

As per `man bash`

> **Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions**, and any characters special to other expansions are  preserved in  the result.  It is strictly textual.  Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces.

**Examples:**

```
echo {1..8}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

n=8
echo {1..$n}
{1..8}
```

**Alternatively** you can use `seq`:

```
seq 1 $n
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: OP has accepted this answer, but I don't see how it solves the problem. How do you convert a string to an integer when you need to read the contents of it as an integer?

Comment: I have added root cause for the problem OP is facing `Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions`